# Extrinsic curvature spinor

Tags: general-relativity, spinors

I know that we can write the tensor quantities in the form of spinor indices. I can found $R_{AA'BB'}$ from Penrose & Rindler 's book. But I'm curious  to know that how about the extrinsic curvature . I cannot find any sources that write down the expression for the spinor version of the extrinsic curvature.